# Exclude plugins from Django cms search

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using `aldryn-search` on my Django CMS site. One of my custom plugins has a ManyToMany field to Django groups, to indicate which user groups may see the plugin (and of course the child plugins). I'm considering this field in the `render()` method of the plugin.

This works fine on the page, but I can't find a way to prevent the regarding plugins from being indexed by the search (which is Elastic Search). Any idea?

Comment: hello there, would you like to completely remove the plugin from search? or just make it so only users allowed to see the plugin can see it in search results?

Comment: hi, both options would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So to exclude the plugin from being searched completely.
You can set `search_fulltext = False` in your plugin class or plugin model.

To exclude the plugin only from users who do not have access to it is a bit more work but is not too complex.

You would have to create a dedicated index class for this plugin and deactivate it from cms page search as shown below.

Then in the dedicated plugin index class, add a `MultiValueField` to hold a list of user ids that can see this plugin, note that you'll have to make sure to only index plugins that have a page attached to them `plugins.filter(placeholder__page__isnull=False)` and also only plugins whose page is published and public.

After finishing the index class/logic, if using solr, then update schema to reflect new field.

Rebuild the index.

Here's an example on how the query could look like:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
   SearchQueryset().models(PluginClass).filter(allowed_user_ids=request.user.pk)
```

Let me know how it goes :)